# Reset password userflow not returning AADB2C90118 in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using the built-in userflow in Azure B2C and when clicking on the "forgot password?" link in the sign-in&sign-up userflow, I get in jwt.ms the error `AADB2C: An exception has occurred`. This seems to be because I am using the page layout version 2.1.2. If I use version 2.1.1, then I get back the expected error `AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password.`

Is that a known bug and how can I fix it? I need 2.1.2 as it returns correctly encoded french characters in the UI.
Thank you for your help

NB: This question has been asked here already https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/284801/reset-password-userflow-not-returning-aadb2c90118.html

Comment: Thanks @Octopus and the page layout for this feature still in progress and please find document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout

Comment: Looks like you have got a confirmation from that link. Would you mind posting an answer for others' reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits should go to amanpreetsingh-msft who provided an answer in the above mentioned link, here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/284801/reset-password-userflow-not-returning-aadb2c90118.html

This is an expected behavior in Layout version 2.1.2 which is still work in progress. The idea is that, when this will be available, by resetting the password one will avoid going back to the app by throwing an error to trigger the password reset.